# Xcode doesn't log any exception / assert / error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, logging

i'm just stuck into an annoying problem. I have used a framework to get some crash report.
that was just workin fine, but suddently, gdb doesn't log any error.
For example when i type

```
NSArray* anArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[anArray objectAtIndex: 5];
```

I just get a sygabrt message. Not that the framework asked me to change Strip Debug Symbols During Copy & Strip Linked Product, Deployment Post Processing and Generate Debug Symbols in my target symbol. What i don't understand is that is repercuting in ALL my project now.
This is very frustrating.

Comment: Did you restart xcode (and perhaps your mac?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSZombieEnabled

Comment: that not working. The fact is i don't understand why i don't have these logs anymore. Seems like a nasty xcode bug...